# Spectral signature doesn’t match band set in SCP Plugin

Tags: qgis, band, scp

I'm trying to do a supervised classification to see land cover change using the Semi-Automatic Plugin in QGIS. After I create my ROIs and try to assess the spectral signature plot for the ROIs, I receive this error: "Spectral signature does not match band set. Calculate spectral signatures again." This shows up as a "Critical' error.

My methodology so far:

- Downloaded my Sentinel-2 image and added only the bands with the same spatial resolution (e.g. B2, B3, B4, B8 for 10 m resolution) into the QGIS layers panel.
- Preprocessed the image and created a band set with those 10 m resolution bands and ticked the box to 'Create a virtual raster of band set.'
- Selected a Training Input in SCP dock, created Macro Classes, and drew a polygon around my ROI.
- Highlighted one of the MC IDs I just drew, added it to the spectral signature plot, and went to asses the spectral signatures and receive the critical error message: "Spectral signature does not match band set. Calculate spectral signature again."

I am at a loss on how to fix this. Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but maybe you have to try to open your image with SCP plugin and stack the bands there. You have to specify that you are using sentinel 2. When you do that, SCP will recognize the bands.